# build a menu from file structure

Tags: c#, asp.net, rad-controls

I am building a menu depending upon the file structure on server. So, this is the file structure:

```
Videos
    Reports 
        Customers
    SetUp
        Customers
        Products
```

So, i wrote this code

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo RootDir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Videos"));
RadMenuItem RootNode = OutputDirectory(RootDir, null);
videoMenu.Items.Add(RootNode);
```

In output directory I'll iterate through them and return them. So, now i wanted output which looks like this:

```
Reports 
    Customers
SetUp
    Customers
    Products
```

I dont want videos to be the parent level. INstead wanted Reports and Setup to be at top. can you please help me.

Comment: A menu for what? WinForms? WPF? Web? What kind of menu? A "regular" menu or a "menu" made with a tree view?

Comment: What are you building the menu for? Winforms? WPF? Web?

Comment: `Server.MapPath()` implies ASP.NET.

Comment: Web Forms.. SOrry forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you'll want to add several parent level nodes to your RadMenu (Reports, Setup, etc.), rather than just adding the single RootNode.  Whatever your `OutputDirectory` method is doing, make it return the children of "Videos" as an IEnumerable of nodes, and add those rather than RootNode.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a recursive function. Something like this:

```
void Main()
{   
    var dirs = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Videos")).GetDirectories();
    CreateTree(videoMenu.Items, dirs):
}

public void CreateTree(IList<RadMenuItem> parantCollection, IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> parentDirs)
{
    foreach (var dir in parentDirs)
    {
        var node = OutputDirectory(dir, null);
        parantCollection.Add(node);
        CreateTree(node.Items, dir.GetDirectories());
    }
}
```